# android use localse to change language

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to make my application multi language, I used two folders for them, the first one is the default `values` inside the `res` folder, the second one is `values-ar` inside the `res` folder. everything is working perfect when the language is english.

Now, i want to change it to `arabic`. I used this code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

when i used that code, the instruction of the application like `cut` and `paste` are changed, but i didn't know who to tell the application to use variables from `values-ar` folder, not from `values` folder.

#### please don't worry about the encoding

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current language and set if condition.

```
String currentLang = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();

if(currentLang == "english"){
      //TODO
 }else if(currentLang == "yourLang"){
     //TODO
 }
```

Hope you will find this usefull.
Cheers

Comment: thanks for your replay, but this is not what i need. there is a very simpler solution which you don't need to add any line of code. the solution depends on the android system to select the values from the specific folder not from the default values foler